# From Excel to splitted Python structures

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, pandas, dataset

I have the following Excel file:

```
ID    Name     Budget
...   ...      ...
...   ...      ...

... some unfilled blank cells

ID    Name     Budget
...   ...      ...

... some unfilled blank cells

ID    Name     Budget
...   ...      ...
```

I want to read this Excel sheet using Pandas (for instance ExcelFile) into separated structures(each table before the unfilled cells constitutes a dataframe/dictionary/...).

I need to do this so that I can process the data in the same structure as well as between multiple stuctures (like summing the budget of a repeating ID or Name in each structure)

What is the easiest way to do this while keeping a reasonable memory performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that read all the data by `read_excel()` and split:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("c:\\tmp\\book1.xlsx", "Sheet1")
mask = df["ID"] == "ID"
nmask = ~mask
s = mask.astype(int).cumsum()
dfs = [x.dropna() for _,x in df[nmask].groupby(s[nmask])]

for df in dfs:
    print df
```

The values in `dfs` are all object.